# ArcObjects: Why is my StandaloneTableCount 0? (IStandaloneTableCollection)

Tags: c#, arcobjects

When I do:

```
IStandaloneTableCollection collection = (IStandaloneTableCollection)MxDoc.FocusMap
```

Then collection.StandaloneTableCount returns 0.

I have created the new table via ArcCatalog and registered it as versioned.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, what I was missing was that the newly created table also needs to be added into the workspace for it to be available on the FocusMap.
So easy, yet no search yielded any help. So I hope this helps some other ArcObjects newbies out into the future. :)